# Is there a name for a song that describes a dance?

Tags: terminology

Some pop songs contain lyrics which describe the steps to a dance. Examples include *The Loco-Motion*, *Time Warp*, and *Cha Cha Slide*.

Is there a specific word for a song of this type?

Answer (score 1):

They are called [**Fad Dances**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_and_fad_dances)

> "In the early 1970s the disco spawned a succession of dance fads including the Bump, The Hustle, and the YMCA. This continued in the 1980s with the popular song "Walk like an Egyptian", in the 1990s with the "Macarena", in the 2000s with "The Ketchup Song" and in the 2010s with "Gangnam Style". Contemporary sources for dance crazes include music videos and movies."

Comment: and that duck up-and-down thing for kids. Can't remember the name. :)

Comment: @Lambie.  Now I can't get your "chicken dance"  out of my head!https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5sIspLfmXM

Comment: Nooooo. :) It's the Duck Song, in French anyway. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNZbMobnxlw What is that in English?? By the way, don't google Danse du Poulet, it's kinda gross.

Comment: "Come On, Baby, Do the Twist" names the dance but doesn't really describe it in any detail as I remember.  Same with "Papa Loves Mambo", one of Perry Como's hits.

Comment: @ lambie... it's the same song! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_VJe5iHrJw

Comment: Shouldn't this be *fad dance* ***songs***? The question wasn't about the name of the dances themselves, but of songs that describe them . . .

Answer (score 1):

I found a web page referring to "instructional dance songs"

https://noisey.vice.com/en_us/article/68anzr/a-brief-history-of-the-instructional-dance-song

And thanks, now I've got a music virus that starts with

```
To the right and to the left.
Forward, side, to-ge-ther.
```